# Get gtk system style color

Tags: colors, background, styles, gtk

I am trying to get system style colors.

```
color = gtk_widget_get_style(window)->
        bg[GTK_STATE_NORMAL];
```

window is my main window and it definitely mapped. I tried with another widgets, GtkStyle's fields and GTK_STATEs, nothing similar to my system style colors.
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks